# Disable highlight of ListView row on mouse hover?

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

When I hover the mouse over a ListView item, the row is highlighted. The ListView in C# does not highlight the ListView row on mouse hover however. Is there's a way I can disable the highlight effect in WinAPI?

Comment: Can you please describe the behavior that you get, and both what window styles and listview extended styles you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to turn off themes for the control.

```
SetWindowTheme(hwndCtl, L" ", L" ");
```

Comment: Do you know how to add the highlight effect (I want to know how to add it in C#).

Comment: `SetWindowTheme(hwndCtl, L"Explorer", 0);` in C++. You may have to p/invoke in C#.

Comment: The MSDN docs are a bit weird. They say to use `L" ", L" "` to disable. But they also describe passing an empty string. Passing `L"", L""`` does indeed disable themes so I think that the code sample is wrong. Why would they have chosen a string with a single space to be special? Very odd.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I think the point is to have a string that's non-null (because that resets to the default), that won't match any of the classes. Of course it's not documented what the classes are (other than "Explorer"). Presumably L"fubar" would work just as well as a space or an empty string.

Comment: Very likely. I always get a bit weirded out when I read that doc that says that `L" "` is an empty string!